# What is $@ in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which I cannot understand.

```
for $i(@myarr)
{
    #some stuff
    eval {
        #some stuff
    };
    if($@)
    {
        print "*** $@ ****";
    }
}
```

1. What does that eval do? Is it a standard Perl command or just some sub?
2. What is the variable $@? It is currently printing a string but I don know where that string is coming from.

Comment: take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to Suic’s answer, see the [English](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?English) module that lets you use more descriptive `$EVAL_ERROR` instead of `$@` and the [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny) or [TryCatch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TryCatch) modules that avoid common traps associated with using `eval` for exception handling. Also, the next time you wonder about a Perl function, `perldoc -f` is your friend (like `perldoc -f eval`).

Comment: Hi zoul thanks for the additional info!
regarding perldoc -f, am I supposed to run it on my interpretor?
I am using Hamilton C Shell which can easily detect the version of Perl from perl -v, but it cannot execute your command.

Comment: I have no idea about Perl on Windows, sorry. You can always just google for “perldoc foo”, works about the same.

Answer (score 19):

`$@` The Perl syntax error or routine error message from the last eval, do-FILE, or require command. If set, either the compilation failed, or the die function was executed within the code of the eval. please read this doc http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Now understood what eval does.